Avoid nginx/fastcgi_pass to do redirect 301 on same url with trailing slash
I have an Nginx reverse proxy, it serves http requests from front with vuejs and an API with php (symfony). There is a behaviour on a specific url that is not expected and I don't get why. If I call https://mydomain.de/api/courses, it redirects to https://mydomain.de/api/courses/ indefinitely until the browser stop through error: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
This is a simplified nginx configuration:
server {
    location / {
        root /tmp
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location ^~ /api {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        set $backend ${BACKEND_UPSTREAM};
        fastcgi_pass $backend;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}


Any idea to solve this issue ?
